# Android activity stack management

Tags: android, android-activity, stack

I have an "a-b-c-d" activity history.
I want to kill activities "c" and "d" and start a new "x" activity, so that the new order becomes "a-b-x".

```
Intent i = new Intent(D.this,B.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
i.putExtra("start_x", true);
startActivity(i);
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("start_x", false)) {
    Intent i = new Intent(B.this,X.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

That's how I'm doing it (and I use it a lot of times). **Is there an easier way to do it?**

EDIT: I forgot to write this: it's necessary to press the back key and go to the "c" activity while in "d".

Comment: What you are doing is the easiest and most straightforward way to do this. You can also add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` to the `Intent` you use to start `D` from `B` and that will reuse the existing instance of `B`. You should then override `onNewIntent()` in `B` and check the extra and (optionally) start `X` from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 2 ways.

**First Way**

In AndroidManifest.xml, for C and D activities add property `android:noHistory="true"`

**Second Way**

In C activity and D activity, at the time of click add a flag.

**Ex:**

```
Intent i = new Intent(C.this, D.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(i);
```

Do same for D activity also...

Comment: I forgot to write sorry. It is necessary to press the back key and go to the c activity while in d

Answer (score 0):

One option is that you can set Activity C & D to have same affinity and can call finishAffinity() to clear activities having same affinity from the current task stack. For more info refer to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAffinity()

Answer (score 0):

added to the above answer of @BHARADWAJ COUNDINYA

**Thirds Way:**

I will manipulate my activity stack like this:

From A to B:

```
//In A
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

> [Activity Stack: A->B]

From B to C:

```
//In B
Intent intent = new Intent(this, C.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

> [Activity Stack: A->B->C]

From C to D(this time I will use finish();):

```
//In C 
Intent intent = new Intent(this, D.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

> [Activity Stack: A->B->D]

Then in D if my sole purpose is to start X when user navigate back:

```
//In D
 protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, X.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

> [Activity Stack: A->B->X]

Now if user navigate back again from X it will land on B:

> [Activity Stack: A->B]

Comment: I forgot to write sorry. It is necessary to press the back key and go to the c activity while in d

Comment: so from a b c d back to c then back key to x am I right?

Comment: then in c check the condition and start x by finishing self, that way c won't be in the stack and when user navigate back from x then it may land on B.